# 12.10 boots to desktop with icons, but no panels, no taskbar

Tags: 12.10

Installed 12.10 from LiveDVD on Dell desktop that ran Ubuntu in original machine.  It boots to plain desktop with icons carried over from 12.04, but no Dash or menu and no taskbars.  Help!

Answer (score 2):

I had this (wallpaper and icons but nothing else) on my mess-around-with-Linux-and-feel-total-hacker-laptop and tried the `dconf` reset but didn't have it and my netbook had no internet connection to install dconf.

So being a complete noob I skipped that and did the `setsid unity` anyway.

And it worked, started the UI nicely :)

No clue what happend, but even after few reboots I still get the proper UI and all, so call it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what is going on with your setup, but I would try to reset Unity and Compiz.

Type the following in to a terminal:

> dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

then

> setsid unity

If this is an issue with Unity settings that will reset your config to default.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I think the dconf-tools must be installed first. `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

Comment: Got an error with that command -- twice.  Something else is screwing me.

Comment: Finally, I resolved the issue by a fresh install of 12.10, overwriting everything (except a few drivers) and eliminating email clients and other similar software.  I chose that resort after over 24 hours of trying, testing, and being rejected by Ubuntu help advice from a dozen or more charitable, expert users, including some from Canonical.  It took an hour to do the fresh install from a LiveDVD (that took me two hours to create) based on a download.  The upgrade is apparently beset by some bugs; it checksummed correct after download.  Saddening experience.  Thanks to all for the  help.

Comment: NikTh - on both of my 12.10 installs (64bit) dconf-editor was installed by default.